# Problems with my code on filesystem in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, filesystems, translation

I have several problems with an exercise in python. I should use Spyder 3.9

The outline of the exercise is as follows:

> Ajeje the librarian recently found a hidden room in the Keras library
> (an amazing place located in Umkansa, the largest village in the White
> Mountains). There he discovered several books containing sheet music
> of ancient Tarahumara and ha songs, so, invited a musician friend to
> take a look. The musician told her it was a sensational discovery,
> since the scores are written in Tarahumara notation, a population now
> extinct, but very famous for having influenced the musicians of the
> Sierra Nevada. To play the songs suggests you have them translated
> into one notation familiar to late Umkansan musicians descendants of
> the Tarahumara, so that they can reproduce them. The Tarahumara wrote
> notes using numbers instead of letters: 0 in place of A, 1 in place of
> B and so on, up to 7 in place of G. The flat (b) and sharp (#) notes
> (see note 3 below, if you don't know what flats and sharps are) were
> followed by a - and a + respectively (for example, 0- means A flat).
> Furthermore, they simply repeated the same number several times to
> represent the duration of the note. For example, 0000 means that the
> note A has a length of 4, while 0-0-0-0- means that the note A flat
> has a length of 4. Pauses were written as spaces: for example, twelve
> spaces represents a rest 12 long. Both notes and rests could extend up
> different lines of the score (for example, starting from the line x
> and continuing on the line x+1, x+2 and so on). Finally, musical
> scores were written from the right to the left and from top to bottom,
> while going back to the top it meant nothing in terms of the musical
> score. Umkansans, on the other hand, usually write notes using
> letters, and each note is followed by its duration (hence, the example
> above it would be written as A4). The flat and sharp notes follow
> respectively by a 'b' or a '#' (for example, A flat is written Ab, so
> the above example would be written to Bb4). Rests are written using
> the letter P, followed by the their duration and no space is used.
> Finally, Umkansans are accustomed to reading music from left to right,
> written on a single line. Since Ajeje knows that you are a skilled
> programmer, provides you with a folder containing the transcript of
> all the Tarahumara songs he found, organized into multiple subfolders
> and files (one song per file). Furthermore, he prepared an index file
> where each line contains the title of a Tarahumara song (in quotation
> marks), followed by a space and the path to the containing file that
> song (in quotes, relative to the root folder). He would like to
> translate all the songs listed in the index e save them in new files,
> each named with its title of the song it contains (with .txt
> extension), in a folder structure corresponding to the original one.
> Also, would like to store in the root folder of the structure created
> an index file containing on each line the title of a song (in
> quotation marks) and the corresponding one length of the song,
> separated by a space. The songs in the index must be sorted by
> decreasing length and, if the duration of some songs is the same, in
> ascending alphabetical order. The duration of a song is the sum of the
> durations of all the notes and rests of which it is composed. You will
> be able to help Ajeje translate the songs Tarahumara in Umkansanian
> songs?
>
> Note 0: A function for is provided below Umkansanize Tarahumara songs;
> after being executed, it must return a dictionary where each key is
> the title of a song and the associated value is the duration of the
> song.
>
> Note 1: the index of the songs to be translated is the 'index.txt'
> file which is located in the directory passed in the source_root
> argument
>
> Note 2: the index of translated songs is the 'index.txt' file which
> must be created in the directory passed in the target_root argument
>
> Note 3: The flat and sharp notes are just "altered" versions. of
> regular notes; for example an A# ("A sharp") is A altered version of
> an A, i.e. a note A which is a half a step higher than regular A; the
> same goes for flat notes, which are half a step lower than normal
> notes; homework-wise, flat and sharp notes they must be treated in the
> same way as regular notes (except for their notation).
>
> Note 4: We use the English notation of the notes A B C D E F G.
>
> Note 5: You can use the 'os' library functions to create the necessary
> directories (e.g. os.makedirs)

Now, I tried to do my code but I have problems with the translation of the notes and the output. In fact I should have as an output, a dictionary with the title of the song and the lenght of the song but I have this type of error:

> AssertionError: Lists differ: ['The clear gym happens genius." 72°, ''*Th[714 chars] 45'] != ['The clear gym happens genius.72, 'The al[660 chars].45°]`.

So It means that I have a list?

I think also that I make some errors in the translation because my output and the output expected are different. For example:

```
4 -6-3464-4-0-23 05
 5 50 66+3 2536 -3 4 -2
1-6152 4 +6 -4 -546-6+1+4 +4
6 0 41 +3-2 0 2 -6 1+5
```

this file of text should be translated into

```
F1A1P1D1Cb1Ab1Eb1E1G1E1Db1Gb1P1E1Cb1P1E1P1Db1P1G1D1F1C1P1D#1G2P1A1F1P1F1P1E#1P1E#1B#1Gb1G1E1Fb1P1Eb1P1G#1P1E1P1C1F1B1Gb1B#1F#1B1P1Gb1P1C1P1A1P1Cb1D#1P1B1E1P1A1P1G1" but however its translated in "F1A1P1D1Cb1Ab1Eb1E1G1E1Db1Gb1P1E1Cb1P1E1P1Db1P1G1D1F1C1P1D#1G2P1A1F1P1P1E#1P1E#1B#1Gb1G1E1Fb1P1Eb1P1G#1P1E1P1C1F1B1Gb1B#1F#1B1P1Gb1P1C1P1A1P1Cb1D#1P1B1E1P1A1P1G1
```

So they are different

My code (I really think is wrong) is:

```
import os
def Umkansanize(source_root: str, target_root: str) -> dict[str, int]:
    index_file = source_root + '/' + 'index.txt'
    d = dict()
    with open(index_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            title, path = line[1:-2].split('" "')

            formatted_title = '' + title + ''

            index_song = source_root + '/' + path
            with open(index_song, 'r', encoding='utf8') as music:
                song_lines = music.readlines()
                translation = translate(song_lines)
                length = count(song_lines)
                d[formatted_title] = length
                dictionary = transform(d)

                os.makedirs(target_root, exist_ok=True)

                target_file_path = target_root + ' ' + title + '.txt'
                with open(target_file_path, 'w', encoding='utf8') as umkansanian_file:
                    umkansanian_file.write(translation)

    file_index = target_root + '/' + 'index.txt'
    with open(file_index, 'w') as index:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            index.write(key + '' + str(value) + '\n')
    return dictionary


def translate(song_lines):
    translated_text = ''
    output = ''
    for line in song_lines:
        for musical_note in line[::-1]:
            if musical_note == '\n':
                continue
            else:
                if musical_note != '\n':
                    translated_text += musical_note
    output = translate_tarahumara_song(translated_text)
    output1 = output.replace("/n", ' ')
    return output1


def translate_tarahumara_song(song: str) -> str:
    def reverse(text):
        temporary_variable = ""
        for i in range(len(text)):
            for k in range(len(text[i]) - 1, -1, -1):
                temporary_variable += (text[i][k])
        return temporary_variable

    def sharp_and_flat(i, text, num):
        count = 1
        second_temporary_variable = ""
        encryption_algorithm = {"0": "A", "1": "B", "2": "C", "3": "D", "4": "E", "5": "F", "6": "G", " ": "P"}
        if i - 2 >= 0 and text[i - 2:i] == text[i:i + 2]:
            pass
        else:
            second_temporary_variable += encryption_algorithm[num]
            if i + 1 < len(text) and text[i + 1] == "+":
                while i + 1 < len(text) and text[i:i + 2] == text[i + 2:i + 4]:
                    count += 1
                    i += 2
                second_temporary_variable += "#" + str(count)
            elif i + 1 < len(text) and text[i + 1] == "-":
                while i + 1 < len(text) and text[i:i + 2] == text[i + 2:i + 4]:
                    count += 1
                    i += 2
                second_temporary_variable += "b" + str(count)
            else:
                while i + 1 < len(text) and num == text[i + 1]:
                    count += 1
                    i += 1
                second_temporary_variable += str(count)
        return second_temporary_variable

    def selection(text):
        count = 1
        numbers = "0123456"
        temporary_variable = ""
        for i, num in enumerate(text):
            if num in numbers and num != text[i - 1]:
                temporary_variable += sharp_and_flat(i, text, num)
            elif num == " " and num != text[i - 1]:
                temporary_variable += "P"
                while i + 1 < len(text) and text[i + 1] == " ":
                    if i + 2 < len(text) and (text[i + 1] == '+' or text[i + 1] == '-'):
                        continue
                    count += 1
                    i += 1
                temporary_variable += str(count)
                count = 1
            else:
                pass
        return temporary_variable

    temporary_to_reverse = reverse(song)
    reversed_text = temporary_to_reverse.replace("\n", "")
    total = selection(reversed_text)
    return total


def count(song_lines):
    len_song = 0
    for line in song_lines:
        for musical_note in line:
            if musical_note == '+' or musical_note == '-' or musical_note == '\n':
                continue
            else:
                len_song += 1
    return len_song


def transform(d):
    d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
    D = dict()
    for tuple in d_sorted:
        D[tuple[0]] = tuple[1]
    return D
```

Sorry if I wrote so much

Comment: FYI you can turn a list of tuples into a dictionary with `D = dict(d_sorted)`

Comment: You need a space between the title and legth: `index.write(key + ' ' + str(value) + '\n')`

Comment: Now I got: AssertionError: {'The clear gym happens genius.': 72, 'The [696 chars]: 45} != {'The clear gym happens genius.': 72, '"T [732 chars]: 45}

Comment: It looks like there's a problem with the way you're reading the song titles. Maybe it shouldn't be `encoding='utf8'`.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to do `dictionary = transform(d)` every time through the loop. You can do it once at the end of the loop.

Comment: Well, it has to be encoding= 'utf8' I think. My problem now is that maybe the chars are translated wrong... I don't understand why in the AssertionError its write that in the first output (the expected one) are less chars than in mine (the second one).

Comment: That's why I think it's encoding, the multi-byte characters are being processed differently.

Comment: What should I use or do?

Comment: What happens if you leave out that argument?

Comment: If i remove utf8 there are the same errors

Comment: Then I'm not sure what the problem is. Try printing the title.

Comment: Why are you concatenating empty strings to the title? `'' + title + ''` That doesn't format anything.

Comment: The real problem isnt this one but the fact that the translation work wrong and I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You haven't explained what's wrong with the translation.

Comment: Like I said even though I've done the translation, my output isnt the output that should be. For example this string "+4 1+5 0 +6 3
-61+11-2 -2 2 +6 
 2 2 0 5 +3+0 4 03-2
 +130 -1+3 5 +1 5 5+60+2-6-0" should be translated in "D1P1G#1P1A1P1F#1B1P1E#1P1G#1P1C1P1Cb1P1Cb1B1B#1B1Gb1Cb1D1A1P1E1P1A#1D#1P1F1P1A1P1C1P1C1P1Ab1Gb1C#1A1G#1F1P1F1P1B#1P1F1P1D#1Bb1P1A1D1B#1P1" meanwhile my output is "D1P1G#1P1A1P1F#1B1P1E#1P1G#1P1C1P1Cb1P1Cb1B2B1Gb1Cb1D1A1P1E1P1A#1D#1P1F1P1A1P1C1P1P1Ab1Gb1C#1A1G#1F1P1P1B#1P1F1P1D#1Bb1P1A1D1B#1P1". As you can see the part "1+11" became "B2B1" but it should be ""B1B#1B1"

Comment: Put that in the question. And if that's what you're really concerned with, leave out the part about the title.

Comment: my fault. You got some advise for me?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not planning on reading your translation code. Maybe someone else will help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.